# Update an object in object - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a lot of properties and with nested objects. I need to update some properties including the ones which are in the nested objects.
What is the best way to do that?

First I tried this way:

```
  adjustedConfig.stars.size = 20;
  adjustedConfig.width = 1800;
  adjustedConfig.disableAnimations = true;
  adjustedConfig.stars.exponent = -0.26;
  adjustedConfig.stars.limit = 10;
  adjustedConfig.constellations.lineStyle.width = 2;
  adjustedConfig.background.width = 4;
```

this approach has 2 problems.

1. It is ugly
2. It doesn't work for me in next js. It says: **TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'size' of object '#'**

So I tried this way:

```
  adjustedConfig = { ...adjustedConfig, stars: { size: 20 } };
```

Here is a problem that it deletes other values in the nested object.

Comment: If this object is managed by next.js, you should be using its methods. That's why `size` is read-only, you're not supposed to be able to update it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another `...` in the nested object:

```
adjustedConfig = {...adjustedConfig, stars: {...adjustedConfig.stars, size: 20}}
```